# Rename files stored in a folder using a table

Tags: r, dplyr, file-rename

I have a folder that contains a large amount of files from miscellaneous sources, mainly photos and videos. I have also a table in Excel with two columns: one with the original name of these files as stored in the folder, and another column with the new name to be renamed with.

My question is: how can I rename the files stored in that folder using as a reference list the table in Excel?

```
library(tidyverse)

# The original files of the photos are stored in a folder
current.folder <- "C:/Users/Tests/Desktop/Field_photos_2019"

# Produce a table with mock-up names for the photos
raw.table <- tibble(IMG = rep(x = "IMG_", times = 10),
                    date.photo = rep(x = c("20190831", "20190901"), each = 5),
                    suffix = paste0(rep(x = "_", times = 10), sample(x = 1:100, size = 10), rep(x = ".jpg", times = 10)),
                    photo.title = paste0(IMG, date.photo, suffix))

# Tidy up the table to make it look as the real table in Excel
# Not sure if the mock-up names also need the file extension?
mock.table <- raw.table %>%
              group_by(date.photo) %>%
              mutate(no = 1:n()) %>%
              ungroup() %>%
              mutate(new.name = paste(date.photo, no, sep = "_")) %>%
              select(photo.title, new.name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R has a `file.rename` function that seems to do what you need

```
setwd(current.folder)
lapply(list.files(current.folder), 
    function(x){file.rename(from = x, to = mock.table[mock.table$photo.title == x,]$new.name)})
```

Comment: I dont think you need the loop with file.rename as it can take vectors